# How to retrieve particular data from id on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to retrieve particular data from id on flutter and want to show data inside list view. I have created view, insert, delete and update operations.i used sqflite
my code is below.

`main.dart` file

```dart
        

class _SqliteAppState extends State<SqliteApp> {
  int? selectedId;
  final textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: TextField(
            controller: textController,
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Grocery>>(
              future: DatabaseHelper.instance.getGroceries(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<List<Grocery>> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(child: Text('Loading...'));
                }
                return snapshot.data!.isEmpty
                    ? Center(child: Text('No Groceries in List.'))
                    : ListView(
                        children: snapshot.data!.map((grocery) {
                          return Center(
                            child: Card(
                              color: selectedId == grocery.id
                                  ? Colors.white70
                                  : Colors.white,
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(grocery.name),
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    if (selectedId == null) {
                                      textController.text = grocery.name;
                                      selectedId = grocery.id;
                                    } else {
                                      textController.text = '';
                                      selectedId = null;
                                    }
                                  });
                                },
                                onLongPress: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    DatabaseHelper.instance.remove(grocery.id!);
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      );
              }),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.save),
          onPressed: () async {
            selectedId != null
                ? await DatabaseHelper.instance.update(
                    Grocery(id: selectedId, name: textController.text),
                  )
                : await DatabaseHelper.instance.add(
                    Grocery(name: textController.text),
                  );
            setState(() {
              textController.clear();
              selectedId = null;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The model class code is below

```
  Grocery({this.id, required this.name});

  factory Grocery.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Grocery(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
    };   } }
```

This is my db_helper class code. I have created view, insert, delete and update operations.

```dart
  class DatabaseHelper {
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database> get database async => _database ??= await _initDatabase();

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'groceries.db');
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: _onCreate,
    );
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE groceries(
          id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
          name TEXT
      )
      ''');
  }

  Future<List<Grocery>> getGroceries() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    var groceries = await db.query('groceries', orderBy: 'name');
    List<Grocery> groceryList = groceries.isNotEmpty
        ? groceries.map((c) => Grocery.fromMap(c)).toList()
        : [];
    return groceryList;
  }

  Future<int> add(Grocery grocery) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert('groceries', grocery.toMap());
  }

  Future<int> remove(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.delete('groceries', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<int> update(Grocery grocery) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.update('groceries', grocery.toMap(),
        where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [grocery.id]);
  }
}
```

Comment: what package do you use for db? and also could you add instance.database cod too?

Comment: i used sqlflite and i added all coding.

Comment: you want type the id that you want and then get it from db and show it in list? @sameera

Comment: I want to select data from id and  view all the data related into select id show selected data inside listview.

Comment: what do you mean by `select data from id`? where is this id come from? @sameera

Comment: Select * from dream where id=6 like that from sqlflite table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to get the data by `id`:

```
Future<List<Grocery>> getGrocerieById(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    var groceries =
        await db.query('groceries', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
    List<Grocery> groceryList = groceries.isNotEmpty
        ? groceries.map((c) => Grocery.fromMap(c)).toList()
        : [];
    return groceryList;
  }
```

Comment: was it what you want? @sameera

Comment: How to show selected  data inside list view in main.dart file

Comment: you can call `future: DatabaseHelper.instance. getGrocerieById(1),` in FutureBuilder @sameera

Comment: @sameera was it what you want?